# Determinant of the Laplacian of a surface is this correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, zeta-functions

given a surface with metric $ g_{ab} $ i would like to evaluate the functional determinant of the Laplacian in the form

$ - \partial _{s} \zeta (0,E^{2})=\log\det( \Delta + E^{2}) $

then i need to evaluate the Theta function $ \Theta (t)= \sum_{n} \exp(-tE_{n})$ for $t >0$ real

since this is too hard :( my idea is to use the approximation

$ \Theta (t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d}} \int dpdx\exp(-tH(x,p)) $

with the Hamiltonian of the surface $ H(x,p)= \sum_{a,b}g^{a,b}(x)p_{a}p_{b} $ summation over indices $a$ and $b$ is assumed :)

my question is if this approximation for the 'Theta function' or Heat Kernel of the Laplacian of the surface is valid, i need the Theta function in order to evaluate the determinant of the Laplacian by zeta-regularization.

Answer (score 1):

I think effective estimate of this is usually considered to be very difficult. A standard reference is Fay's book on kernel functions and analytic torsion. In particular, for genus $g\ge 3$ there is no closed formula in literature for arbitrary metric. For genus $g=1,2$ the determinant of Laplacian can be expressed via $\theta$-functions, but the derivation is involved. Some standard references are:

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104159171
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02096935

It is actually not a trivial fact that the "discrete approximation" approaches the continuous limit when $t\rightarrow \infty$. This is a big topic, so some Googling may help.